# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML not working when using variable

Tags: html, reactjs, escaping

I'm creating an SPA using React that searches data and displays results. Each result follows the following model

```
{
  "title": "A Title",
  "body": " &lt;li&gt;escaped html&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;that sould be rendered&lt;/strong&gt;.&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;/ul&gt;"
}
```

The `body` property is always an escaped html that should be rendered in a component. This component looks like this:

#### Code

```
function SearchResult({ title, body, favourite }) {
  return (
    <article className="SearchResult">
    <section>
      <i className={`icon-star${favourite ? ' marked' : ''}`} />
      {title}
    </section>
    <section
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: body }}
      className="SearchResult-body"
    />
  </article>
  );
}
```

but the body of each result is not being rendered correctly, instead, it shows the html as a text
[image]
[image]

The issue is that it only happens when I create the component passing a variable to the `body` property

```
results.map((result, index) => (
      <SearchResult key={index} title={result.title} body={result.body} />
    ))
```

But if I do this, it works fine

```
<SearchResult
    title="A title"
    body=" &lt;li&gt;escaped html&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;that sould be rendered&lt;/strong&gt;.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;"
  />
```

Why is this different? Is there any preprocessing that I should add to the value before passing it in the property that is added by default when I use the fixed value?

#### Demo

A demo of this issue can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jbc4kc)

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your behavior. Both methods work identically for me.

Comment: @MikhailLitvinov I added a link to a live demo of the issue to my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7825) only occurs when you give it an escaped html.

A solution implemented by [@sergiotapia](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7825#issuecomment-250367019) involves creating a helper function to unescape the html string to make it work.

```
htmlDecode(content) {
  let e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = content;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

```
<section
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlDecode(body) }}
  className="SearchResult-body"
/>
```

However as [@brigand](https://github.com/brigand) mentioned and I'll quote "*Unescaping it could allow for XSS attacks and incorrect rendering.*" so this might not be the perfect solution for this.

See [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/73052oo2nj)

Comment: I saw the issue you mentioned, and what you say about XSS attacks is the reason I didn't adopt that solution. Nevertheless, if not best solution appears, I guess I will have to adopt it and use [dompurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) to prevent XSS attacks.